# Why v.push_back() is not reading data inside while loop?

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, stl

In the code below, why am I not able to print the elements of vector? Not even their size. Can you please explain the reason?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,k=2;
    cin>>n;
    vector< int >v;
    while(n!=0){
        if((n%k==0)&&(k<10)){
            n=n/k;
            v.push_back(k);
        }
        else if((n%k!=0)&&(k<10)){
            k++;
        }
    }
    cout<<v.size()<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, `n` won't be updated inside the loop when `n = 11` and the loop will run infinitely.

Comment: [Ok, the size is printed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pameJWbbGv4YYgBY) for `n = 0`.

Comment: Please describe your desired behavior if you want us to fix your code.

Comment: Even with positive `n` input smaller than 10, `n=n/k;` won't make `n` to `0` due to the `n%k==0` condition.

Comment: @MikeCAT, what if n=64? Vector should have 6 elements with size of 6. Please clarify.

Comment: The vector had 6 elements after converge, but their size should be 4 (implementation-defined) and their values are all 2. [https://wandbox.org/permlink/TKQctRi0lYpe3fa5](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TKQctRi0lYpe3fa5)

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). tl;dr; Replace it with the correct header files so that everyone can compile your program.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, I got it what you are saying. that n will never gonna be zero and so loop will run infinitely .I will just replace (n!=0) with (n!=1) in while loop.

Comment: Changing `(n!=0)` to `(n!=1)` won't solve the issue in `n = 11` case. Is it guaranteed that such case won't be inputted or just you are going to think about it later?

Comment: @MikeCAT for prime numbers I still have to make another block!

Comment: Then how about `n = 143`, which is not a prime number?

Comment: @MikeCAT limit of n is from 1 to 100;

Comment: Then how about `n = 91`?

Comment: @MikeCAT that's why there is no supernatural number for 91 and that's what I am trying to find out.